# Download Facebook Group Files from my School Automatically

Tags: php, facebook

I've searched and searched, so if I'm repeating a question my apologies.

I'm trying to implement some type of app, code, api that will extract my schools facebook group files to a folder on our schools student website. I am the admin for both locations, and I have a facebook developer account. The front end of the site is Joomla!, I dont know if this is pertinent info.

Its easy for us to post outlines on the group page, but when its time for us to take boards it would be nice to have these files somewhat organized, and also for the next class to have access.

I was hoping to automatically download these group files to an external folder either on our server, or on my computer so that when I have time I can group them by class and block.

Any ideas or direction is most appreciated.

Comment: You will most likely want to use cURL to scrape the site and capture the data.  I'm not quite sure what kind of data you are trying to grab, but cURL can probably do it.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm trying to grab the files section of our group. pdfs, docs, etc. will the method you described work for this?

Comment: Yes, most definitely if you are able to access them from the web.  You may run into some authorization hurdles if trying to access them behind a login screen, but cURL has ways to send usernames/passwords/cookies, etc.  I will write you a code snippet to try.

Comment: ok, that would be awesome.

Comment: awesome. i'm going to experiment with what you've supplied. i'm still learning, but i understand the gist of what I need to do. i've just never actually done it. i'll respond today or tomorrow when I've arrived somewhere. best regards, and thanks a ton.

Comment: I'd like to ask a few questions, but you've got me half way already, so I'm hesitant to "push my luck." But you only live once right, so here it goes. 1. I should set up a cron job to make this run automatically? 2. How am I going to get through to a closed group? 3. Outlines are uploaded routinely, so how can I make each file name unique (eg is there a way to save each file with the date and time)? thank you x1000 for the help, i'll get it soon enough.

Comment: ok. so I'm sorry if I'm drawing with crayons, but I'm fairly certain I need to implement a facebook login which will let me authenticate with an access token instead of app token so I can use the user_groups permission. after that I should be able to pull what I need using the group id, the files field, and the code you provided. something like https://graph.facebook.com/groupid/fields=files

Comment: so i guess now my question is how do i add the stuff above to the existing code? also, where in the code could i specify a directory on my server, would it be somewhere in fwrite?

Comment: I made an edit to my post to address some of your questions.

Comment: this is great! i only have one more question and i'll be set. I played around with the facebook API, and I'm now able to pull the group feed in html with it only displaying the posts with outlines. The problem I face now is centered around how the link is displayed within the feed. Is it possible to make the $url part of your code search for "download_link" in my feed and then download the link that comes after it `"https://x/x\x.docx"`?

`"message": “xxx”,
"download_link": "https://www.facebook.com/download/xxx/xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\document.docx",
"updated_time": “TIMESTAMP”`

Comment: Yes, it most definitely is possible.  And relatively easy to make happen.  Is the data you get back in JSON?  Or better yet, can you send me the link to the full output in http://collabedit.com?  If the data is in JSON format, PHP has built-in functions for parsing the data.  Then you can just loop through each download link and act on it.  In your case, you will probably then set the `$url` variable with the link and then run it through your cURL function.

Comment: Hello. I'm fairly certain it is JSON because the url has JSON inside. https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP-NUMBER/files?limit=3&`format=json`&access_token=XXX  I've got a sample at http://collabedit.com/uyt2e but I've removed the names and access token. Hopefully that will work. I can't say thank you enough.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. When I set a cron job is it going to download outlines more than once; duplicates?

Comment: Okay, so I marked up some stuff on the collabedit.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: looks great! in regards to the backslashes, were you saying that backslashes in general are a problem, or just the ones where I changed the url?

Comment: if there is a way I can buy you a beer, please advise. thanks for everything.

Comment: Ha, not necessary. If my answer was helpful, just mark it as accepted. Thanks, man!

Comment: well... firstly, apologies for this dragging on. I'll be referencing http://collabedit.com/uyt2e for these _last_ two questions (hopefully the last). 1) At line 79 ($json_data), you said if you were getting data back from the api you would just use that. I'm guessing this is where I use my URL (`https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP-NUMBER/files?limit=#&format=json&access_token=XXX`). So, using php how would I call this URL? (Yes, I'm a lost cause) 2) When I do pull the URL the "download_link" path has backslashes automatically; it's not an option I can control. Is this problematic?

Comment: How are you "pulling the URL" that you mentioned?  However you're doing that, that's what you need to do.  I, personally, would use cURL for this, but if you're already interacting with the API, then just use that.  If you use my sample data, you will have the same results hard-coded every time you run it.  If the download path has backslashes in it, then you may need to escape them.  Give it a whirl with live data and see if it breaks.  If it does, then just do a find/replace to escape the slashes.  If it's already working for you with the backslashes, then you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's a simple script to grab an image and save it to your server.  This particular example is for a `jpg`, but should also work with PDFs, Word docs, etc.  Just change the filename and where to save it.  Also, make sure that the place you are trying to save the file to has permissions for the web to write to it.

```
<?php


$url = 'http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/26539728/2/stock-photo-26539728-red-and-golden-curl-party-streamers-hanging.jpg';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    error_log('CURL Error ('.$url.'): ' . curl_error($ch));
}



$fp = fopen("file.jpg",'w');
fwrite($fp, $data); 
fclose($fp);             


print "File download complete";
```

EDIT: 
Okay, so this is just a section to address some of the questions you asked in the comments.

If you'd like to set this up to download files every so often, then your idea of using cron would be a good way to do this.  As far as making your file names unique, this is pretty easy.  Here's an example:

```
<?php

// THIS WILL SET THE FILE NAME TO 'outlines/outline_2014-02-21_06-49-20.pdf'
$file_name = "outlines/outline_".date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").".pdf";

// SET THE FILE TO OPEN TO BE YOUR NEWLY CREATED FILE
$fp = fopen($file_name,'w');
```

So in this example, you would make a folder named `outlines` and make sure that it was writable by the web.  Then you can just store your files in there.

The other question you have is in regards to the Facebook login.  I'm not familiar with the Facebook API, so I can't really help you there.  It may be a good idea to make a separate post specifically for the API questions you have.  A long time ago, I used Facebook as one means to validate an email address.  I don't know if I'd be comfortable posting it here because it was a long time ago (read, old code is not something I'd be proud to show today) and I don't even know if it still would work.  Anyway, sorry I can't "kick it in the driveway" for you, but hopefully I got you well on your way.